# So what do I do when nobody seems to respond?

Tags: support

Do I repost it in a few days? I must get this fixed...

Comment: Once you have enough reputation points by contributing to the site yourself, you can increase exposure of your question by setting up a bounty.

Comment: I gave it a small bounty to draw some more attention to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question will get bumped up if there is an edit, or new answer. The system also periodically bumps questions to the front page.

If you need a faster response, you could also ask for a little help in our chat room, called [Root Access.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Answer (score 3):

Please do not repost or edits to just bump, there is a high chance we figure out it is a duplicate.

Check out [How to get your questions answered?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/) from the Super User Blog, which can help you improve your question to get it answered. It goes in full details on the various things you can do.